# Display authenticated and anonymous content in a view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, view, facebook-login, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm newbie in web development.

Consider site that user can be logged in (e.f Facebook log-in)

Assuming I know if a user is logged in or not (I'm on my way to find how ;) - is it possible that on the same view (.cshtml) - part of the elements will be hidden if user anonymous or will be revealed if user is logged-in? you know - something like nice attributes or conditions (in short - to put the logic on the same view and not to manage two .cshtml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm personally not a fan of having if statements in my view's as they can easily begin to get cluttered, especially if you are using roles.

This is the way I prefer to do it to avoid that.

1. Create an html helper containing the logic like this abstracted away:

   ```
   namespace System.Web.Mvc
   {
       public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
       {
           public static MvcHtmlString UserMessage(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
           {
           string welcomeFormat = "Welcome, {0}";
           var isAuthenticated = htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
           var name = htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
           var message = isAuthenticated ? string.Format(welcomeFormat, name) : string.Format(welcomeFormat, "anonymous!");
           return new MvcHtmlString(message);
          }
      }
   }
   ```
2. Call this method within my view like this:

   ```
   <p>@Html.UserMessage()</p>
   ```

If you are new to web development the code for the Helper extension might look a bit overwhelming but you only end up writing that once and the code you use to call it elsewhere is a lot simpler and re-usable.

Here is an article about Html helpers for more info:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/649394/ASP-NET-MVC-Custom-HTML-Helpers-Csharp

***Update***

Forgot to mention this technique too, which again avoids the if statements.

Create two partial views say `_auth.cshtml` & `_unauth.cshtml`.

Create an action that checks if the user is authenticated & returns the relevant partial i.e

```
public ActionResult FooContent()
{
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        return PartialView("_auth");
    }
    else
    {
        return PartialView("_unauth");
    }
 }
```

Then call the action from within your view like this:

```
@Url.Action("FooContent", "Contoller");
```

This can also be used to check roles and return different partials.

Comment: Thanks appreciate both answers and will try them out and let you know soon. I guess there isn't best practice here? like some web design pattern here?

Comment: Personal choice really, give them both a try out in a solution to see which you prefer. :)

Comment: I completely forgot the updated method in my answer. I think that is better practice than the if statement too. :)

Comment: Thanks appreciate your time :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, views can have logic.

Here's an example of code that displays different content to the user depending on if they are logged in or not.

```
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <p>Welcome, @User.Identity.Name!</p>
}
else
{
    <p>Welcome, anonymous!</p>
}
```